# What is about polling after I/O service is stopped

Tags: boost-asio

Recently I'm working with boost asio and there is a statement I believe ambiguous to readers in documentation

```
The poll() function runs handlers that are ready to run, without blocking, until the io_service has been stopped or there are no more ready handlers.
```

To verify my comprehension, an experiment is conducted below

```
boost::asio::io_service io;

boost::system::error_code error;

boost::asio::signal_set signals(io);

signals.add(SIGINT);signals.add(SIGTERM);signals.add(SIGQUIT);

/* asynchronous wait on signal conditions to stop io service */

signals.async_wait([&io](const boost::system::error_code & code, int val){
    io.stop();
});

/* the only main thread polls all file descriptors to dispatch ready handlers */

while(!error)
    io.poll(error); /* this is where I expect error arise upon io stopped after signal of interrupt from console is conducted to asynchronous wait handler */
```

But it appears that call to poll always returns success even that io service is stopped. So the program would not exit by having error as condition of the loop. So my question is, am I right and is there other mechanism I missed to exit the loop of calling poll? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to process a stopped `io_service`'s event loop via `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()`, or `poll_one()` is not specified as being an error.  The [`io_service::stop()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html) documentation specifies that it affects `poll()` by causing subsequent calls to `poll()`  to return immediately until `reset()` is called.  Furthermore, a normal exit from [`io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) is documented as occurring when the `io_service` has been stopped, accentuating that  attempting to process the event loop on a stopped `io_service` is not an error:

> A normal exit from the `run()` function implies that the `io_service` object is stopped (the `stopped()` function returns `true`).

To exit from the loop, consider changing the predicate so that the loop stops upon error or when the `io_service` has been stopped:

```cpp
while (!error && !io.stopped())
    io.poll(error);
```

Comment: very clear. That's also what I was thinking about. Thanks for clarification.